# MySQL, what if an unique record gets deleted?

Tags: mysql, unique-key

If a unique record gets deleted, will it be replaceable? Or they're like the IDs that don't afflict the count?

Comment: if you use auto_increment is not a problem if a  there are "holes" in  the sequence of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is replacable.

The unique constraint only takes care the value is not in the same column twice. If you delete a row, you can insert a new row with the same values without a problem, or after deleting you could update the field of a existing row to the value of the deleted field.

Comment: It will not be replaced by default, though. You'd have to explicitly do it.